# VPN protocol that only requires a key to authenticate

Tags: networking, vpn, protocol

I have been given (by one of local banks) following configuration to connect to a VPN network:

host servers:

10.1.1.xx
10.1.2.xx
10.1.3.xx
10.1.4.xx

peer:

213.86.52.xxx

key:

combination of letters, numbers and special characters of length: 30 digits.

for example:

abcdefghijk123456789*$Aghdkisr

I am unable to identify the type or protocol of the VPN used in the above configuration. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Have you tried just tried asking the provider?
And while you wait just try random VPN protocols.
Or port scan common VPN ports to see if they work, so you can try udp/500 or udp/1194 for openvpn or ipsec

Comment: I've tried scanning all common VPN ports but none of them respond, plus - all common VPN protocols require Username and Password to authenticate, but I was given only 30 digit 'key'.  I won't be able to contact them for a week - they are having some technical maintenance.

Comment: Unfortunately then, techie007 is right. Unless you get more information such as connection details you are kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1):

"all common VPN protocols require Username and Password to authenticate" - this is incorrect.  Site-to-site VPN (for example) doesn't use user names, just the tunnel info and the shared key (not the *only* way to do it, but it's common).

You're going to need to go back to whomever gave you that info and get the rest of it (tunnel type, protocols used, key life times, etc.).

Based on what settings you seem to have, there's not enough information for us you help you, or for you to setup a VPN anyway.

Comment: Even user vpn connections may not require a User and Pass, it may just require a cert.